# Why does Windows Azure Tools insist that my SSL configuration is incorrect?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure

I'm about at the end of my rope with Windows Azure Tools and SSL configuration in the ServiceDefinition/ServiceConfiguration files in a cloud project.

At first, I had a web role with RDP enabled (and certificate configured, etc).  All that worked for a long time.  Then I added an SSL certificate for an https endpoint.  It wouldn't deploy because of certificates not being installed in my localmachine/personal store, etc.  After messing with it, somehow I've gotten into a bad state where even if I completely remove all configurations having to do with RDP or SSL, I still get this from the emulator:

```
Windows Azure Tools: Warning: The SSL certificate 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.PasswordEncryption' for endpoint 'HttpsIn' of role 'My.Web' was not found in the local machine's certificate store.
Windows Azure Tools: Warning: Certificate identification setting 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.PasswordEncryption' for role 'My.Worker' specified in the service configuration file is not declared in the service definition file in the Certificate or as part of an SSL endpont
```

Like I said, there is no such configuration in any of my files, and when there were, they hadn't changed from the time that they worked until this.  I tried deleting the dftemp directory where the deployments get placed, I've cleaned and rebuilt the cloud project, I've killed visual studio and the emulator(s), and still always wind up back in the same place.

Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: I added the 'azure-sdk-1.7' tag on purpose because there was no tag for the Azure SDK.  I thought it would be useful to help narrow down questions that are really about the SDK, and not so much about the other parts of the Azure platform which would be covered by the 'azure' tag.

Comment: There are other tags for the SDK already, one for the .net platform and one for python.  I see nothing here that demands a *version-specific tag*.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what happened, but after leaving for the day and coming back this morning, I found that a system reboot seemed to clear the issue.  I have no idea why, but this seems to have resolved itself.

Answer (score -2):

for first error, you have to remove certificate from certificate section of your service configuration file(cscfg). This certificate is used for encrypting your RDP password.

For second error, I think if you remove above section, it will automatically disappear. Also ensure that you have removed modules RemoteAccess, RemoteForwarder from service definition file(csdef)

Comment: I already stated in my question that I removed all configurations relating to certificates, including the RDP-related configurations.